# Bootstrap multicheckbox checked attribute

Tags: razor, checkbox

I have a razor view and using bootstrap-multiselect.css. I am showing checkboxes but i cant make checkboxes checked with my code. Thanks for answers.

```
<select name="@cat.Title" id="catandsubcat" multiple="multiple" class="form-control">
  @foreach (SubCategoryVM subcat in cat.SubCategoryVM)
  {
    <option value="@subcat.Id" @(Model.Any(x => x.SubCategory_Id == subcat.Id)) : "checked" : "" }>
      @subcat.Title
    </option>
  }
</select>
```

My browser renders this.

```
<li class="checkList active"><a tabindex="0">
  <div class="aweCheckbox aweCheckbox-danger">
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="multiselect-1">
    <label for="multiselect-1" class="checkbox">Peyzaj</label>
  </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem with some javascript.

```
 var mySubCats = [];

@foreach (var d in subcatsarray)
{
    @:mySubCats.push("@d");
}
    $('select').multiselect('select', mySubCats)
```